# Linq int to string

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-entities

how do I cast and int into a string? None of the following do works:

```
from s in ctx.Services
    where s.Code.ToString().StartsWith("1")
    select s

from s in ctx.Services
    where Convert.ToString(s.Code).StartsWith("1")
    select s

from s in ctx.Services
    where ((string)s.Code).ToString().StartsWith("1")
    select s
```

**EDIT**

The error I get is:

*`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression`*

Comment: The first two ought to work...can you elaborate on what "None of the following...work" means?

Comment: Are you just not getting any results back?  Have you confirmed that the "Code" column contains a value that starts with a "1"?

Comment: www.linqpad.net is great for learning Linq (and pretty much anything else in .NET). It's free and highly recommended. Also, its $19 Intellisense is great.

Comment: He is using Linq to Entities not Linq to sql - this means much of the advice here is not applicable...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Linq to Entities does not support as many conversion of functions to server hosted sql.

ToString (on anything) is one of them

Here's the list of [supported functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx)

This has been asked before on Stack overflow specifically [asking how to convert an int to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities)

Comment: Your first link is dead.

Answer (score 54):

With EF v4 you can use [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx).  So your code would end looking like this:

```
from s in ctx.Services
where SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)s.Code).StartsWith("1")
select s
```

**EDIT**

As Rick mentions in his comment, the reason for casting the int to a double (decimal probably works too) is that the function does not have an overload for int.

Comment: This worked for me! The only funny thing about this is that apparently there is no overload of this function for 'int'.  That's why Brian is boxing this as a double before calling the function above.  In my opinion this needs to be marked as the answer for this question.

Comment: This, too, worked for me. I agree with Rick Arthur that this should be the answer.

Comment: this answer is now more useful than mine, if the op wants to change the accepted answer that would be fine, otherwise I'll add a note to indicate that, from v4 you should use your answer.

Comment: +1, but I would add that I found I had to .Trim() before the .StartsWith() because EF was left padding the number with spaces.

Comment: @JoelBrown - thanks! Saw this approach in a number of places, but I could not figure out why it wasn't working. The Trim() call got it straightened out.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue

```
        IQueryable<Street> query = db.Streets.AsQueryable();
        query = query.Where(street => street.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(keyword))
                        .Take(10)
                        .OrderBy(street => street.Name);

        var list = query.Select(street => new
        {
            street.StreetId,
            Name = street.Name + " " + street.Suburb.Name + " " + street.Suburb.State.Name + " " + street.Suburb.Postcode

        });
```

street.Suburb.Postcode was throwing 'cannot convert non primative type error' as its an int? After following shuggy's link I fixed by adding .AsEnumerable to force int? -> string conversion 'client side' i.e. LINQ to Objects. i.e.

```
var list = query.AsEnumerable().Select(street => new
        {
            street.StreetId,
            Name = street.Name + " " + street.Suburb.Name + " " + street.Suburb.State.Name + " " + street.Suburb.Postcode

        });
```

Comment: Thank you, you definitly saved my day.
Adding `AsEnumerable` was the key here.

Comment: Will AsEnumerable() cause the whole database table to be loaded into memory?

Answer (score 2):

When using LINQ to Objects you can use the ToString() helper.

Answer (score 1):

cast IQueryable to IEnumerable since IQueryable inherits IEnumerable. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx - specifically: 'Enumeration causes the expression tree associated with an IQueryable object to be executed.' I think the important thing is 'The definition of "executing an expression tree" is specific to a query provider'.

IQueryable is very powerful but misused in this context.

Comment: This was suggested in [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765423/problem-getting-guid-string-value-in-linq-to-entity-query).  The nice thing about this approach is it works for non-numerical data, such as Guids.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this workaround and it worked for me:

```
from s in ctx.Services
where (s.Code + "").StartsWith("1")
select s
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to do it.

```
int[] x = new int[] {11,3,15,7,19};

var j = from s in x where s.ToString().StartsWith( "1") select s.ToString();

Console.WriteLine( j );
```

Comment: this doesn't help him - he's using linq to entities

Answer (score -1):

```
from s in ctx.Services.ToList()
    where s.Code.ToString().StartsWith("1")
    select s
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var items = from c in contacts
select new ListItem
{
    Value = String.Concat(c.ContactId), //This Works in Linq to Entities!
    Text = c.Name
};
```

I found that SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.Age) did not work for me either the field is of type Nullable

Took me a lot of searching over the last few days of trial and error to find this.

I hope this helps a few coders out there.

Comment: I'm trying to select SelectListItems and casting an int ID into the string "Value" property, same as your example. But with this code I get `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Concat(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`