# Problem getting GUID string value in Linq-To-Entity query

Tags: linq-to-entities, guid, tostring

I am trying to write a GUID value to a string in a linq select. The code can be seen below (where c.ID is GUID), but I get the following error:

*Unable to cast the type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.*

```
var media = (
                from media in Current.Context.MediaSet
                orderby media.CreatedDate
                select new Item
                {
                    Link = "~/Media.aspx?id=" + media.ID,
                    Text = "Media",
                    Time = media.CreatedDate
                }
            ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to break apart the query into L2E and L2O:

```
var q = from media in Current.Context.MediaSet
        orderby media.CreatedDate
        select new
        {
            Id = media.ID,
            Time = media.CreatedTime
        };
var media = (
                from m in q.AsEnumerable()
                select new Item
                {
                    Link = "~/Media.aspx?id=" + q.Id.ToString,
                    Text = "Media",
                    Time = q.Time
                }
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked like a charm. To bad they dont have a simplier way to get the string value of the GUID though.

Comment: This worked great!  Thanks for the insight.  I like this much better than having to resort to [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228318/linq-int-to-string), which doesn't work for anything other than a number.