# Comparing GUID to string in LINQ to Entites throws error

Tags: c#, linq

EDIT, this is not a duplicate. The suggested SO links want me to call `ToString()` but I am running a `.COUNT()` and trying to do a greater than comparison so calling `ToString()` is not a correct answer.

I am trying to fill a variable using the `IF` shortcut but when I run it I get the error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Guid Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

The code I am running is

```
IsAdmin = (db.yaf_prov_RoleMembership
             .Where(rm => rm.UserID == UserKey
                          && rm.RoleID == Guid.Parse("adsfasd654asdf816asdf"))
             .Count() > 0) ? true : false;
```

If I take away the `Guid.Parse` and do a straight up comparison then I get the error

> Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type System.Guid and String

What needs to be done in order to compare a GUID to a string in a LINQ query?

Comment: what is the type of `RoleID` ?

Comment: [read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8009272/2436549)

Comment: @Selman22 That is the GUID in the DB.

Comment: I saw those two posts but if I do `ToString()` then I can't run .Count() and do the comparison.

Comment: do the guid.parse before and store it in a variable adminGuid. 
Then compare the Guid's or the Guid.ToString() with String.Equals(str1, str2).

Comment: what @Pieter21 said. the problem is not parsing the string into a GUID, the problem is that LINQ tries to pass that function off to the EF provider, and it doesn't know how to parse a string into a GUID.

Comment: @Pieter21 I am kind of pissed I did not think of that, it worked. If you want to submit it as an answer I will mark it so

Comment: I like Sergey's answer better than mine anyway. It also explained what went wrong and gave a nice other improvent. I'll collect my accepted answers elsewhere.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't know why Dave deleted his answer - you should just move string parsing out of store expression. Otherwise Entity Framework tries to convert `Guid.Parse` method call to SQL, and fails to do that:

```
var adminRoleID = Guid.Parse("adsfasd654asdf816asdf");
```

Also use `Queryable.Any` to simplify your query:

```
IsAdmin = db.yaf_prov_RoleMembership
            .Any(rm => rm.UserID == UserKey && rm.RoleID == adminRoleID);
```

Answer (score 1):

The key part of your first error reponse is this: `[...]into a store expression`.
If you parse the guid first and store in a var, I think it should work:

```
 var guid = Guid.Parse("adsfasd654asdf816asdf");
 IsAdmin = db.yaf_prov_RoleMembership
             .Any(rm => rm.UserID == UserKey && rm.RoleID == guid );
```

Whenever you do operations that the 'thing' that executes your LINQ queries does not know how to handle, you'll get this error. In this case, it's entity framework not knowing how to translate Guid.Parse into an SQL statement/ 'store expression'.

EDIT: Modified to use `.Any`. as per Sergey Berezovskiy's answer

Comment: Copy-paste from my answer. You even didn't rename `adminRoleID` to `guid`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Doubt it was a copy paste, answered within 1 minute of each other and there's pretty much only 1 way to write this, i would've written it exactly the same too, if you downvoted i suggest you undo that)

Comment: I answered the exat same thing before you though, thought I included attribution to you in my edit message but evidently I did not

Comment: @RonanThibaudau I write about copy-pasting only when I'm totally sure about it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8yjy9ujgrm0ae8/Screenshot%202014-08-18%2002.31.15.png and as you can see this answer is not downvoted.

Comment: As you've added a description for why his code does not work, I'll upvote yours. My whole intention for adding that EDIT: was in fact to point credits in your direction, I failed at that so my apologies.