# C# Join two tables using Include. Data comes from a Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am very new with C# and need some help. I am working on someone elses code and they are pulling data from a Model. I am trying to join two tables and need to use Include but the error is '==' cannot be applied to Guid and IQueryable. Could someone help with this please. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Yes, I am.

Comment: what are you trying to do in .Select part of the linq query?

Comment: You would want `itemIds.Contains(mi.Id)` but that wouldn't be right within the `.Select`. `.Select` is for selecting the fields you want to return.

Comment: I want to return a field named ParentId to know if it is empty or not. That's all but I need both tables linked to get that answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Guid' and 'string' in linq to entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009041/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-system-guid-and-string-i)

Answer (score 3):

`.Where()` represents your filter. `.Select()` represents what you want back. If you just want the entities back you don't need a `.Select()`.

If you have an association between menu items and MenuItemProgramData, for example, a MenuItem holds a reference to a MenuItemProgramData then you don't even need the first ID select statement:

```
return context.DbMenuItems
  .Where(x => x.MenItemsProgramData.Plu == plu);
```

Note: If your context defines `DbSet<T>` for your various top level entities, you can just use context.Ts rather than `.GetItems<T>`.

If the relationship exists then this is the preferred approach. Let SQL do the work. The consumer of your method can further `.Select()` the applicable data, sort it, paginate it, and even append `.Include()` if you do want to interact with the entire entity graph.

If you don't have a relationship between the menu item and that program data, and know that the # of item IDs from the first query will remain relatively small (say, sub-100) then:

```
var itemIds = context.DbMenuItemProgramDatas
  .Where(x => x.Plu == plu)
  .Select(x => x.MenuItemId)
  .ToList();
```

Without the `.ToList()` you are dealing with an IQueryable which EF would potentially still attempt to translate to SQL statements when later consumed. By using `.ToList()` it will execute the SQL and populate a `List<int>`. (Assuming the menu item ID is an int)

To get the `IQueryable` menu item data rows:

```
return context.DbMenuItems
  .Where(x => itemIds.Contains(x.Id));
```

And that is it.

Edit: Based on the comment "I want to return a field named ParentId to know if it is empty or not. That's all but I need both tables linked to get that answer."

Additionally, looking back at the original code, the naming of the method is a bit misleading. GetItemProgramDataForSubItems implies returning MenuItemsProgramData rather than MenuItems... However, if ParentId is a property of MenuItem, then the caller of this method can use:

```
var hasParentId = context.GetItemProgramDataForSubItems(plu)
  .Any(x => x.ParentId.HasValue);
```

If the ParentId is on the MenuItemsProgramData:

```
var hasParentId = context.GetItemProgramDataForSubItems(plu)
 .Any(x => x.MenuItemsProgramData.ParentId.HasValue);
```

Beyond that, you may want to elaborate on what your entities and relationships look like, and what exactly you aim to accomplish from your method or business logic.

Comment: Thank you for your in depth explanation. It is tough when you are trying to learn a new language with no one really to ask. Thanks for your help!