# How can I implement String.Concat(object, object) to L2E framework?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have two long type columns that I want to concat during sql query. Using Linq to Entities making it impossible, because it only supports `String.Concat(string, string)`.

I'd like to know how can I implement this function myself and add it to the L2E framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the point in doing the concat in SQL ? You can do it in a projection when you receive the data :

```
var query = from foo in db.Foo
            select new { foo.X, foo.Y };

var result = from foo in query.AsEnumerable()
             select foo.X.ToString() + foo.Y.ToString();
```

> I'd like to know how can I implement this function myself and add it to the L2E framework.

I don't think that's possible, unless you want to implement your own EF provider...

Comment: I was thinking about extending it.

Comment: I doubt that is possible... If you want to know more about how the provider is implemented, have a look at it using Reflector. I suggest you buy a stock of aspirin beforehand ;)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Can't you convert them to strings first, by doing `String.Concat(long1.ToString(), long2.ToString())`? Or is this not understood by the framework either?</strike>

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228318/linq-int-to-string), which talks about some workarounds for this problem. Maybe you can adapt something to work here as well?

Comment: ToString() is not supported by L2E. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx

Comment: @Eran Betzalel I see. After a bit of digging, this looks like a common problem - there are a few related questions on SO. Not sure if it's helpful, but would be at least worth a look.

Comment: The solution on these questions is not for me (my current situation suggests that using ToList will simply get all the table's content).