# LINQ to Entities - get all related entity field into a string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a Person Entity something like that

```
PersonId
PersonName
PersonPhone
```

I have a House Entity

```
HouseID
HouseType
HouseSize
```

Both Entities are related with many to many relation.
I need to have all the HouseType for a person (which has many houses) into a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily concatenate multiple strings from a sequence with the [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) method.

In your case you'll have to first *project* the list of `House` entities into a list of `House.HouseType` strings and then *aggregate* them into a single string:

```
var houseTypes = person.Houses.Select(i => i.HouseType).AsEnumerable();
var emptyResult = "0";

return houseTypes.Any() ?
    houseTypes.Select(i => i.ToString())
              .Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next) :
    emptyResult;
```

Alternatively you could simply say:

```
var houseTypes = person.Houses
                       .Select(i => i.HouseType)
                       .AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(i => i.ToString());
return String.Join(", ", houseTypes);
```

which will return an *empty string* when the `houseTypes` sequence is empty.

**Update:**

If you're using Entity Framework 4 or above, you can use one of the [built-in SQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3293050/26396) to perform the conversion to string directly in the database:

```
var houseTypes = person.Houses
                       .Select(i => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)i.HouseType))
                       .AsEnumerable()
return String.Join(", ", houseTypes);
```

Comment: My houseType is not a string so I get an Error "Cannot implicity convert type 'string' to 'short'"

Comment: @Kulpemovitz If the `HouseType` property is of type short you can just convert to a string with `ToString()`. I updated my example.

Comment: Great.But now it fails if the person has no house(s). but I still need the person in the result

Comment: what do you think?                                        person.Houses.Count > 0 ? vs.person.Select(i => i.HouseType.ToString()).Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next) : "0"

Comment: @Kulpemovitz You're most likely getting exception stating that the `Sequence contains no elements` when the `Select` method returns an empty sequence. I updated my answer.

Comment: I will stay with my syntax. Thank you

Comment: This doesn't work in linq to entities (both .ToString and .Aggregate can't be translated). It does work in linq to objects, but that's not what the question is tagged as.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like?:

```
var data = context.People.Where(p => p.PersonId == <id>).SelectMany(p => p.Houses).Select(h => h.HouseType);
var result = string.Join(<separator>, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var houseTypes = person.Houses
    .Select(i => i.HouseType).ToList();

return string.Join(" ", houseTypes.Select(x=>x.ToString()));
```