# linq to entity join on string equals int

Tags: asp.net, linq

I saw this post [Linq int to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228318/linq-int-to-string), and tried it

```
            var personalInfoQuery = from t in crnnsupContext.Tombstones
                                    join i in crnnsupContext.InitialEducations on t.InitialEducation equals SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)i.InitalEducationID) 
                                    where t.RegNumber == 25952
                                    select new CPersonalInfo 
                                    { 
                                       Tombstone = t, 
                                       InitialEducation = i
                                    };
```

in the database `t.InitialEducation` is char, `i.InitalEducationID` is int, but the retrieved result is null. I am pretty sure the value is not empty in the SQL server. So I think the problem is `SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)i.InitalEducationID)`

when i remove the join statement, it got this person's information.

Does anyone know why. thanks

Comment: I assume because InitialEducation is an int not a string?

Comment: t and i are the instance of your class. You are missing the property Name. I mean t.VariableName.

Comment: @PankajGarg what do you mean? can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally find the reason!!
 `t.InitialEducation` is **nvarchar(1)** in the database, `i.InitalEducationID` is **int**, after I modified to `SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)i.InitialEducationID, 1)` it works!

"1"  is the length of the returned string, the default length is 10, I guess there are some extra space.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` method, I'm assuming you're using EF as the underlying LINQ provider, no?

From the information given, it would appear that you're looking to do a 1 to many join on those properties. The code you've written could coalesce (not enough info on the context to be certain) as an INNER JOIN in SQL, so to force the LEFT JOIN behavior, you can add a `.DefaultIfEmpty()` call:

`crnnsupContext.InitialEducations.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: but i am sure the result should not be empty