# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

when I trying to run following code.

```
var result = from c in db.brand
             where c.title.contains("test")
             select c.title + "-" +c.brand;

List<string> lst = r.ToList();
```

it gives following error.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.

Comment: This explains why this happens - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228318/linq-int-to-string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest fetching the title and the brand in an anonymous type, and then performing the string concatenation in-process:

```
var list = db.Brand.Where(c => c.Title.Contains("test"))
                   .Select(c => new { c.Title, c.Brand })
                   .AsEnumerable() // Rest of the query in-process
                   .Select(x => x.Title + " " + x.Brand)
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var result = from c in db.brand where c.title.contains("test") select c;
var finalResult = result.ToList().Select(ss=> ss.title + "-" + ss.brand);
```

Comment: You'd need to call `ToList` *again* to get a `List<string>` which appears to be desired. Additionally, that will fetch *all* of the properties of each entity, when only the title and brand are really needed. Finally, there's no need to call `ToList` as the intermediate step - `AsEnumerable` can avoid creating the intermediate list.

Comment: ToList or AsEnumerable forces to execute the query over the datacontext after that String functions will be available to collection. Good catch Jon, thx

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
var result = from c in db.brand where c.title.contains("test") select new { c.title + "-" +c.brand }
```

Comment: Using an anonymous type isn't going to help here - and that code wouldn't even compile, as there's no name for the property in the anonymous type.

Comment: yes, you are right. did learn a lesson here: always test the answer!