# Int equals String in Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Basically I have this problem:

```
var item = 
    from itemCT in listC
    join ditemRef in servRef.Repository.GetQuery(efContext).DefaultIfEmpty()
    on itemCT.specialStringID equals ditemRef.refID
    into DitemRef
```

The problem is that `itemCT.specialStringID` is a string ( didnt design it ... can't change it ) 
Still I am required to make the join work. Any hints ?

Looking for related [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228318/linq-int-to-string) I've tried using `SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)ditemRef.refID` without success.

Any hints towards the light at the end of the tunnel helps

Comment: Convert one of the two to the other type using the `Convert.To[Type]` methods. It should be ok to use in those queries.

Comment: You sir are correct . Talk about over thinking it . Please write it as a proper answer so I can mark the question as answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many methods found in the [`System.Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) class are supported within a LINQ-to-Entities query.  Use it to convert one of the two types to the other.  Then you'll be able to write your query.