# Type Conversion Error: System.Linq.IQueryable(string)' to System.Linq.ParallelQuery(int)'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have two tables in my database Element and Entity, given an el_id(element id) i would like to extract the ent_id(entity id) from the Element table and ent_type_id(Entity type) from Entity table, i have an ent_id column common in both the tables but it is int in Element table and String in the Entity table, following is the code, help me resolve it.

```
  var ent_ids = _context.Elements.Where(e => el_ids.Contains(e.el_id)).Select(el => el.ent_id);
  var ent_type_ids = _context.Entities.Where(e => ent_ids.Contains(e.ent_id)).Select(el => el.ent_type_id);
```

Error:

```
Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable(string)' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery(int)'
```

This comes for the second line of the code.

Edit: added models from comment below.

Entities Model:

```
public partial class Entity 
{ 
    public int ent_id { get; set; } 
    public Nullable<int> document_id { get; set; } 
}
```

Elements Model:

```
public partial class Element 
{ 
    public int el_id { get; set; } 
    public string ent_id { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check out Brian Cauthon answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228318/linq-int-to-string).  You should be able to do something like this:

```
//according to the models you posted...

//this is a collection of strings right?
var ent_ids = _context.Elements.Where(e => el_ids.Contains(e.el_id)).Select(el => el.ent_id);

//e.ent_id should be an int right?.
var ent_type_ids = _context.Entities.Where(e => ent_ids.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)e.ent_id))).Select(el => el.ent_type_id);
```

For whatever reason there is no overload of SqlFunctions.StringConvert() that takes int, so you have to cast to double.

Comment: ErrorCannot convert type 'string' to 'double'

Comment: Do i have my assumptions backwards?  Can you show the models you are using?

Comment: @Prithvi Dammalapati i updated my answer with some comments.  can you please verify that what I am suggesting is correct by stepping through your code.  It seems like what I have should work based on the models you provided.

Comment: var el_ids = _context.Ent_El_Tags.Where(t => tag_list.Contains(t.tag_id)).Select(e => e.entel_id);
            var ent_ids = _context.Elements.Where(e => el_ids.Contains(e.el_id)).Select(el => el.ent_id);
            var ent_type_ids = new List<int>();
            foreach (var el in ent_ids)
            {
                if (el != null)
                {
                    var id = int.Parse(el);
                    ent_type_ids.Add(id);
                }
            }
return _context.Entity_Type.Where(e => int_type_ids.Contains(e.type_id));
        }

Comment: Sorry for the un-formatted code, but i am not sure how to do it, this is how i made it work