# How to use Html.DropDownListFor() helper in the right way

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a signup form. I want users can select their pet's race using a select list in html. So i decided to use Html.DropDownListFor() Html helper.

In my model:

```
public class PetModel
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public short gender { get; set; }
    public short type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int raceID { get; set; }
    public int birthYear { get; set; }
    public int weight { get; set; }
    public bool neutered { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> raceList { get; set; }
}
```

And i want to populate a drop down list for raceList that users can select their pet's race.

So i created a controller for a partial view

```
public PartialViewResult _SignupPet(PetModel model)
{
    model.raceList = entity.PetRaces.Select(w => new SelectListItem { Text = w.name, Value = w.id.ToString() });

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

And in my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.raceID, Model.raceList)
```

But i'm receiving this error.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.

Now i'm wondering about this. I generally use drop down list to select an id and show user a text instead of ids. How will i use this Html.DropDownListFor() helper in my projects. Am i using a wrong approach?

Comment: Could you pass in w.name as both text and Id? Then use the name in your controller action? I've had similar issues, LINQ cannot convert the ToString().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Unique ID for the `SelectListItem` needs to be a string. You cannot do a conversion in the LINQ as it won't translate. I have got around it by using the name as both text and Id as in my case it was unique.

Another example of this same question here: [Linq int to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228318/linq-int-to-string)

Comment: I have a FK relation Pets anf PetRaces in my DB. So i can't set it to the string.

Comment: Its a limitation in LINQ to Entities. You could extract the data and then loop through to create the List<SelectListItem> in code. That way you can do the conversion. Ugly solution but no other way past it

Comment: Thanks for your support. I've found a workaround thanks to you :)

Comment: Remember and mark solution accepted if it answers your question. Glad to help, shame it's not elegant. I had same issue a few weeks back

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't solve my original problem but i found an alternative solution. In my controller i changed the code

```
model.raceList = entity.PetRaces.Select(w => new SelectListItem { Text = w.name, Value = w.id.ToString() });
```

to

```
model.raceList = entity.PetRaces.Select(w => new SelectListItem { Text = w.name, Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)w.id).Trim() });
```