# Comparing String Column with Int column

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-ctp5

I'm working on EF CTP5 Code First development with an existing database. I need to get the data from two tables by comparing columns of different types.

For example - Here `p.ColumnA` is `varchar` as `q.ColumnA` is `int` but the values might be the same for few records. So, I'm trying to do `Convert.ToInt32` which does not work. I do not have complete control over the database to modify the table.

```
from p in context.TableA
from q in context.TableB
where p.ColumnZ == "ABC" &&
  (p.ColumnA == null || Convert.ToInt32(p.ColumnA) == q.ColumnA) &&
  (p.ColumnB == null || p.ColumnB == q.ColumnB)
select p.ColumnC
```

Can someone suggest a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Need more information.  Is Convert.ToInt32 throwing and exception?  Are you getting other errors?  What is happening exactly?

Comment: I'm getting an exception when using Convert.ToInt32. Exception: _"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write a linq statement that interacts with the entityframework it trys to convert all the commands to SQL. Because there is no sql command for Convert.ToInt32 it is throwing an error.
 [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities) describes a way to cal the sql functions for converting types. It should help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that the LINQ statement would be converted to SQL expression, that's why my statement would fail. I knew about SqlFunctions but was always reluctant to use those methods 'coz I'm targeting my app towards both Sql Server & Oracle eventually, so will these SqlFunctions methods get translated to Oracle when used with their provider?

Comment: I'm not sure, but my guess would be no. `SqlFunctions` exits under `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace which is spacific to Sql Server. You could get lucky though. The only other option would be to load the dataset into memory and do the type conversion on the .Net side.

Answer (score 1):

As the other posters have explained, LINQ to <strike>SQL</strike> Entities doesn't know how to translate `Convert.ToInt32` into a SQL expression (LINQ to SQL can apparently handle this). From what I can tell, it doesn't support `int.Parse`, either. But since you're just doing an equality comparison (rather than greater/less than), you should be able to achieve the same result by converting the `int` to a `string`, rather than converting the `string` to an `int`.

```
from p in context.TableA
from q in context.TableB
where p.ColumnZ == "ABC" &&
  (p.ColumnA == null || p.ColumnA == q.ColumnA.ToString()) &&
  (p.ColumnB == null || p.ColumnB == q.ColumnB)
select p.ColumnC
```