# How to avoid converting to INT array using Contains in Entity To Entities queries?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

`sIDs` contains IDs of string type. In second query I want to get all records with ids that are contained in `sIDs`. Because `sIDs` is string array I get error in `where sIDs.Contains(t.Id)`. I cannot either to use `where sIDs.Contains(t.Id.ToString())` because EF doesn't support `ToString` in query. I thought to convert `sIDs` to int array and then I could use `where CONVERTED_TO_INT_IDs.Contains(t.Id)`.

Is there another way to do this?

```
var sIDs = (from t in cxt.myTbl
            select t.Parameters).ToList();

var oList = (from t in cxt.myTbl2
             where sIDs.Contains(t.Id)
             select t).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the answer here: [Problem with converting int to string in Linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities)

(btw that's the first google match when searching for "ef tostring")