# LINQ lambda - convert int to string

Tags: c#, .net, linq, exception

i'm trying to compare a int with a string in the join method of linq lambda, like this:

```
database.booking.Join(database.address,
                      book => book.bookno,
                      afh => afh.addressid.ToString(),
                       (book, afh) => new { booking = book, add = afh })
                .Where(book => book.address.name == "test");
```

but i'm getting an error on the ToString():

> System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How do i solve this?

Comment: Try to use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)afh.addressid)` instead `ToString();`

Comment: @Poku linq-to-entiites does not support any conversions like conert.Tostring() and convert.ToInt32 , convert.ToDatetime..

Comment: @Poku My best suggestion is first retrive the records from database into list and then do conversion and comparison on that list ..then it works for you...

Comment: but how would i join the data when i can't do that compare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you working with Linq to SQL? Linq is trying to convert your lambda to sql query. Unfortunately, `ToString` is not so easily supported.

You can materialize your tables with `ToArray()` before join, but it can be expensive.

Look at [this article](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/2008/08/24/LINQ-to-Entities-what-is-not-supported.aspx) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities).

Comment: as you mention this whould be too expensive in my case :(

Comment: Yes, but look at the links - they might be helpful :)

Comment: the performance is actually not that bad with this solution, so i will this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var bookinger = database.booking.Join(database.address,
                         book => book.bookno,
                         afh => afh.addressid,
                         (book, afh) =>
                         new { booking = book, add = afh })
                     .Where(book => book.address.name == "test")
                     .Select(new { booking, add = add.ToString() });
```

Comment: this would fail when compiling. book.bookno = string and afh.addressid = int.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this??

```
var bookinger = 
    database.booking.Join(database.address,
        book => book.bookno,
        afh => Convert.ToString(afh.addressid),
        (book, afh) =>
        new { booking = book, add = afh })
    .Where(book => book.address.name == "test");
```

Comment: Hi Dave. What did you edit in here? Did I made some silly mistake again :P