# Different behaviour if cast bigint on SQL Server and SQL LocalDB

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, localdb

I have following function on SQL Server and LocalDB:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertToLong]
(
    @Value Varchar(200)
)
RETURNS Bigint
AS
BEGIN
    If ISNUMERIC(@Value)<>1
    Return 0
    Else
    Return Cast(@Value as bigint)

    Return 0
END
```

when calling this function like this:

```
SELECT dbo.[ConvertToLong]('13668433347')
```

I receive different results:

> SQLServer: `13668433347`

> LocalDB: `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.`

Any ideas what is the problem and how to fix it for LocalDB?

Comment: There's no difference. The error complains about `int` not bigint. Is there a typo perhaps?

Comment: Note the error: "converting expression to data type *int*". Make very sure you haven't overlooked a simple difference *you* introduced.

Comment: Side note, don't use `isnumeric`; it's a terrible function. Just use `TRY_CONVERT`. Something like `SELECT dbo.ConvertToLong('1.23')` is going to cause your function to error. Also, why do you have a wayward `RETURN 0` at the end of the function?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There is no typo I have copied the create statement just to be sure that there is no difference.

Comment: But why not just do `SELECT TRY_CONVERT(bigint,'13668433347');` @PiotrAuguscik ? Why rely on a flawed function (`ISNUMERIC`)? There's not need for a user defined scalar function here; you're simply reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @JeroenMostert THe problem is related somehow to if statement - without it cast works. It seems that somehow if block forces conversion to int (at least this is my current understanding)

Comment: @Larnu 1. Because I need it as function for EF. 2. I would like to know the source of issue

Comment: Entity Frame work can use built in T-SQL Functions, and EF2 has it's *own* functions to convert a `String` to a `Long`.

Comment: @Larnu I have .NET 4.7 and EF 6

Comment: So, what's wrong with the [`Convert.ToInt64` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint64?view=netcore-3.1)? Why do this in SQL Server if you want to do this in Entity Frame work? Why use a flawed user function if you "*must*" do it in SQL Server and not the function `TRY_CONVERT` which is available in alll **supported** versions of SQL Server (including those only in extended support). This has a smell of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @Larnu Convert.ToInt64: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int64 ToInt64(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Seems like *that* is the question you should be asking, @PiotrAuguscik .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert.Int64 Is Not Reconized LINQ To Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10095276/2029983)

Comment: @Larnu I am already using methods that ARE available in SQL Server but the problem is that it doesn't work the same way. Yes, `TRY_CONVERT` works because it allows me to ommit `if` BUT it does not explain why the if enforces cast to int.

Comment: @Larnu no it doesn't because the value that needs conversion is in SQL not memeory.

Comment: I am actually surprised that the question got downvotes. The OP is specific on what they are doing, unlike many other.

Comment: What are the differences in `SELECT @@VERSION, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id = DB_ID()` between the instances? If there is a behavioral difference between the databases while using the exact same function definition, my money is on a bug in scalar UDF inlining (introduced in SQL Server 2019). If this hunch is correct, you can use `WITH INLINE = OFF` in the function definition to disable it. Otherwise, an unrelated problem in plan generation is still a possibility, but less likely.

Comment: yeah, looks very like an inline scalar UDF issue, `Return 0` uses a literal of type `int` so chances are that somewhere it does an incorrect `CONVERT_IMPLICT` to `int` - probably this issue is already fixed in a CU

Comment: reproed on 15.0.2000.5 - the problem is that it gets inlined as `CASE WHEN CASE WHEN (0) = (0) THEN (1) ELSE CASE WHEN (0) = (1) THEN (1) ELSE (0) END END = (0) THEN (0) ELSE CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,CASE WHEN (0) = (0) AND CASE WHEN (0) = (1) THEN (1) ELSE (0) END = (0) THEN (13668433347) ELSE CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint,CASE WHEN (0) = (1) THEN (0) ELSE NULL END,0) END,0) END` - No longer repros on 15.0.4013.40 RTM-CU2 so fixed in CU1 or 2

Comment: @Larnu - I imagine the downvotes are because people think that the OP must be describing things incorrectly due to the message about casting to `int` - whereas this issue is perfectly reproducible as a scalar UDF inlining bug. A common problem on SO is that people just dismiss issues they don't understand rather than trying to understand them.

Comment: Seems like, @MartinSmith , that good updates management would have avoided this problem in the first place. :)

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is you are trying to reinvent the wheel. Every supported version of SQL Server has the function `TRY_CONVERT` which returns `NULL` if the value cannot be converted.

`ISNUMERIC` is also very flawed. Things like `ISNUMERIC('1.23')` and `ISNUMERIC('7e2')` return `1`, however, both `CONVERT(int, '1.23')` and `CONVERT(decimal(10,2),'7e2')` fail. Also `ISNUMERIC('')` returns `0`, however, `CONVERT(tinyint,'')` returns `0`, not an error.

As a result, the answer is use the inbuilt function, `TRY_CONVERT` (or `TRY_CAST`):

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(bigint,'13668433347');
```

If you want to return `0` in the event of a conversion error you can use `ISNULL` and if you want to retain `NULL` values a `CASE` expression. So something like:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN YourColumn IS NOT NULL THEN ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(bigint,YourColumn),0) END;
```

There are plenty of articles on why `ISNUMERIC` should be avoided as well:

- [Is It Time To Stop Using IsNumeric()?](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/time-stop-using-isnumeric/)
- [Why IsNumeric() is no good](https://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Why%20IsNumeric%20is%20no%20good.aspx)
- [Fifteen Things I Hate About ISNUMERIC](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/02/fifteen-things-hate-isnumeric/)
- [Stop using ISNUMERIC, it’s (probably) wrong](https://wp.larnu.uk/stop-using-isnumeric-its-probably-wrong/)

Comment: It would be great to understand why this answer is not helpful (Piotr Auguscik, as your reputation went down by 1, I can deduce it was very likely yourself), and I will be more than happy to improve it. I've added multiple articles on why `ISNUMERIC` is bad, if you don't believe the brief outline I give in the answer.

Comment: I know which values are passed to this method - no digits after comma - so no `ISNUMERIC` is not a problem event if it is not adiviced to use the question is not abouit it but thats your only focus here. No I am not trying to reinvent the wheel - this starting sentence only shows how rude you are and not trying at all understand the core issue of different behaviour between sql server versions.

Comment: Using a user function to convert a `varchar` to a `bigint`, while implementing `ISNUMERIC` instead of using a built in function is exactly what reinventing the wheel is, @PiotrAuguscik . It's not rude, it's a simple fact I am afraid. I am sorry if you feel that it's being rude, however, it's simply not. If you do, however, truly feel that statement is "rude" then you can flag by answer as *"**rude or abusive**"* and a moderator van review it.