# Not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have looked at all the examples related to this but have not been able to solve my issue.

I am creating a dropdownlist in asp .net mvc3.

I have a repository which returns:

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetPropertyTypeSelectList()
    {
        var propertyTypes = from p in db.PropertyType
                                orderby p.PropertyTypeDescription
                                select new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Text = p.PropertyTypeDescription,
                                    Value = p.PropertyTypeId.ToString()
                                };
        return propertyTypes;
    }
```

My viewmodel looks like this:

```
public class AddPropertyViewModel
{
    public Property Property { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PropertyTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FurnishedTypes { get; set; }
}
```

My controller for "create" action for HttpGet looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult AddProperty()
    {
        AddPropertyViewModel viewModel = new AddPropertyViewModel
        {
            PropertyTypes = websiterepository.GetPropertyTypeSelectList()

        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

and the view is like this:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property.PropertyType)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Property.PropertyType, Model.PropertyTypes)
    </div>
```

I am getting the error above. From what I have read it looks like ToString() is causing the problem. But I am not sure how to correct it.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities

Answer (score 21, accepted):

LINQ to SQL doesn't know how to translate the `.ToString()` call to a SQL expression.

So replace:

```
var propertyTypes = 
    from p in db.PropertyType
    orderby p.PropertyTypeDescription
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = p.PropertyTypeDescription,
        Value = p.PropertyTypeId.ToString()
    };
```

with:

```
var propertyTypes = db
    .PropertyType
    .OrderBy(x => x.PropertyTypeDescription)
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = p.PropertyTypeDescription,
        Value = p.PropertyTypeId.ToString()
    });
```

Notice the `.ToList()` call to eagerly execute the SQL query after building the expression up until the `OrderBy` clause and then do the `.ToString()` on the client (LINQ to Objects instead of LINQ to Entities) where the `.ToString()` expression is perfectly supported.

So here basically we are constructing a SQL query up until the OrderBy clause (including) and then will call .ToList to eagerly execute this query and fetch the resultset on the client. Then we continue chaining with a .Select statement. But we are no longer doing any LINQ to Entities or SQL stuff. We are now doing LINQ to Objects because all the resultset is now in-memory. And doing .ToString in LINQ to Objects doesn't pose any challenge.

Another possibility is to use the `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` built-in function that knows how to translate it to SQL. This way you are keeping it lazy:

```
var propertyTypes = 
    from p in db.PropertyType
    orderby p.PropertyTypeDescription
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = p.PropertyTypeDescription,
        Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)p.PropertyTypeId)
    };
```

Comment: if I use SqlFunctions.StringConvert((int)p.PropertyTypeId) then I get an error saying "This call is ambiguous between the following models or properties" It works when I change it to decimal or double.

Comment: I think it has to be ToList() instead of List()

Comment: Yes it should be ToList() but unfortunately edit is not possible.