# Getting Cannot implicitly convert int to string when creating a combobox from from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to populate a combobox in a creation view inside MVC 3. This is what i've done so far:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var db = new ErrorReportingSystemContext();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Locations
          .Select(c => new SelectListItem
          {
              Value =c.id,
              Text = c.location_name
          });
        ViewBag.locations = items;
        return View();
    }
```

However when i try to run it it gives a compilation error:

`Cannot implicitly convert int to string`

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities) post i read that doing

```
Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.ContactId)
```

would fix the problem however when i try to do that i get the following error:

`the name 'SqlFunctions' does not exist in the current context`

What i'm i doing wrong?

**Update:**

doing `Value = c.id.ToString()` gives the error:

`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that EF cannot translate the casting to string or the `.ToString()` method.

So you need to evaluate the DB query (with calling `.AsEnumerable()`) before selecting into the `SelectListItem`s

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Locations
      .AsEnumerable()
      .Select(c => new SelectListItem
      {
          Value = c.id.ToString(),
          Text = c.location_name
      });
```

However this approach has some performance problems because the generated SQL query will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Locations ...
```

So if the Locations table has 50 columns EF will load the data from all them although later you only need data from two columns.

You can tell to EF which columns should it load with first selecting into an anonymous type then into the  `SelectListItem`s:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Locations
      .Select(c => new
      {
          c.id,
          c.location_name
      });
      .AsEnumerable()
      .Select(c => new SelectListItem
      {
          Value = c.id.ToString(),
          Text = c.location_name
      });
```

And the generated query will look like somehting like this:

```
 SELECT id, location_name FROM Locations
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i just tried the first one and it worked like a charm!. If you don't mind, can you explain better the difference between the two? i didn't understand that about the columns that you posted

Comment: @EH_warch I've extended my answer, I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably complaining that `Value` expects a string and you're trying to store an `int` in it.

Try:

```
Value = c.id.ToString(),
```

Comment: I get the following error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in db.table.tolist())
{
                Combobox.Items.Add(item.field.tostring());
}
```