# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I'm using the following code :

```
using(var sd=new dataEntities())
{
var listofdata=sd.users.where(d=>d.id.ToString().Contain("2"));// id as int
// error : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
}
```

I looked at the site but did not find answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with converting int to string in Linq to entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the SQL Function to translate the ToString method.

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)id)
```

Answered Here:
[Problem with converting int to string in Linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities)

Comment: i'm use => var listofdata=sd.users.where(d=>SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?)d.id).ToString().Contain("2"));// 
// error : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Don't use the .ToString() method.  The StringConvert does that for you.