# Function for int similar to string.contains

Tags: c#, string, int

I have a textbox bind to an `int`. There is a Search button which gives result on the basis of text in textbox. If the text is **12**, all results having **12** should appear.

Such being the case for `string`, I would have used **string.contains**. But I don't know what to do in case of `int`.

I am using LINQ to filter out results.

```
int securityId = Convert.int32(filterColumn.Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
queryResults=queryResults.Where(generaldata=>generaldata.SecuritiesId.Equals(securityId));
```

But this isn't working. I tried following

```
string securityId = Convert.ToString(filterColumn.Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);                                
queryResults=queryResults.Where(generaldata=>generaldata.SecuritiesId.ToString().Contains(securityId));
```

But getting LINQ exception that I can't use ToString in expression.

Comment: Post some code where you are getting issue?

Comment: Linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx)

```
string securityId = Convert.ToString(filterColumn.Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);    
queryResults=queryResults
      .Where(gd=>SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)gd.SecuritiesId).Contains(securityId));
```

P.S: `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` has no overload for int and that's why the casting to double has been done.

Comment: What I have to import to include SqlFunctions ?

Comment: @naveen : I just found out, I have to make query SQL independent. Thus, I cannot use this approach. Is there some other alternative?

Comment: why does int.Equals dont work? for me .Equals did not work on certain LINQ scenarios and == worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

i think you should check for less than coz for eg if you count from 0 to 100 and check if it contains 12 then yes it contains 12 because

```
12 < 100
```