# Can SqlFunctions work with Dynamic Linq?

Tags: entity-framework, dynamic-linq

Is it possible to get SqlFunctions to work with Dynamic Linq? I noticed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828290/sqlfunctions-stringconvert-and-dynamic-linq) from the SO site which seems to suggest that it is possible, however, every time I run this query below in a .NET project (not .NET Core):

`query.Where("SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?)Property).Contains(\"x\")");`

It spits back a message that:

`No property or field 'SqlFunctions' exists in type 'Entity'`

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me. Check you have created your own custom DLinq with added SqlFunctions type to predefinedTypes as per the post.

Personally I'm adding SqlFunctions dynamically to my DLinq. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18313782/525788 for guidance.