# Linq UNION query to select two elements

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq

I want to select 2 elements from my database table using `LINQ` query and I saw an example which use `UNION` I don't have much experience but I think that maybe this is what I need but I get an error which I can not fix and I'm not sure if it's fixable anyway. So here is my query:

```
    IList<String> materialTypes = ((from tom in context.MaterialTypes
                                   where tom.IsActive == true
                                   select tom.Name)
                                   .Union(from tom in context.MaterialTypes
                                   where tom.IsActive == true
                                   select (tom.ID))).ToList();
```

Which as it seems is complaining about trying to use `UNION` on `IQueryable` with `IEnumarebale`. I tried to fix that by adding `ToString()` like this - `(tom.ID).ToString` which led to cleaning the error underline in `Visual-Studio-2010` but in runtime I get:

```
{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}
```

Ty, Leron.

Comment: Why aren't you just selecting `new { tom.Name, tom.ID }` instead of using `Union`?

Comment: I want to use the data as my `DataSource` if I try with it gives an error that can not convert from anonymous type to string.If I add `ToString()` right before `.ToList()` I get another convertion error - this time from `char` to `String` and the `Union` is solution that I saw for these kind of situations. Is there another way?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

EDIT:

Ok I found why the int.ToString() in LINQtoEF fails, please read this post:
[Problem with converting int to string in Linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities/3292773#3292773)

This works on my side :

```
        List<string> materialTypes = (from u in result.Users
                                      select u.LastName)
                       .Union(from u in result.Users
                               select SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) u.UserId)).ToList();
```

On yours it should be like this:

```
    IList<String> materialTypes = ((from tom in context.MaterialTypes
                                       where tom.IsActive == true
                                       select tom.Name)
                                       .Union(from tom in context.MaterialTypes
                                       where tom.IsActive == true
                                       select SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)tom.ID))).ToList();
```

Thanks, i've learnt something today :)

Comment: Again - `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` The mistake from my original post was an inner exception. This is what I get when I try your way. I think the same as with brackets.

Comment: Lol, I'll go to lunch and test it after. If it works gonna accept your answer

Comment: Wow I would never gonna think of that. Thanks a lot. It works for me too!