# How to union two lists of different types by common columns?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a lotpens and lot history, both have a column a,b,c.
I want to be able to Union this using LINQ and have a where condition (date).

```
public async Task<int> CountInPenLot(DateTimeOffset date)
{
    var lotPens = await _context.LotPens.ToListAsync();
    var lotHistory = await _context.LotHistories.ToListAsync();
    // union lotpens and lot history on columns a,b,c where condition date
    //continue my logic

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022405/linq-union-query-to-select-two-elements

Comment: Are you just trying to count the number of entries, as that's what the method signature implies? It's really not clear why you want to *union* them.

Comment: once I have done the union I want to count the total number in column c.

Comment: So you want to *sum* column c?

Comment: DavidG Yes I want to sum column c. based on the where condition

Comment: Can you add that information to your question? I was a little confused reading David's answer until I read the comments :)

Comment: SELECT  lp.LotId, lp.PenId, lp.HeadCountInPen  AS Head
      FROM scoFeedlot.LotPen AS lp 
    
     UNION
     SELECT LotHistory.LotId, LotHistory.PenId, IIF(LotHistory.Direction = 1, LotHistory.Head * -1, LotHistory.Head) AS Head
      FROM scoFeedlot.LotHistory      
      WHERE CAST(LotHistory.MovementDate AS DATE) > '2017-7-27' AND LotHistory.IsPending = 0 AND LotHistory.IsCancelled = 0.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only want to sum the values in column `c`, the easiest thing is to just run 2 queries and add the together.

```
public async Task<int> CountInPenLot(DateTimeOffset date)
{
    var lotPensSum = await _context.LotPens
        .Where(x => x.DateColumn == date) //Filter on the date
        .SumAsync(x => x.c); //Sum up column c

    var lotHistorySum = await _context.LotHistories
        .Where(x => x.DateColumn == date)
        .SumAsync(x => x.c);

    return lotPensSum + lotHistorySum;    
}
```

Comment: SELECT  lp.LotId, lp.PenId, lp.HeadCountInPen  AS Head
      FROM scoFeedlot.LotPen AS lp 
    
     UNION
     SELECT LotHistory.LotId, LotHistory.PenId, IIF(LotHistory.Direction = 1, LotHistory.Head * -1, LotHistory.Head) AS Head
      FROM scoFeedlot.LotHistory      
      WHERE CAST(LotHistory.MovementDate AS DATE) > '2017-7-27' AND LotHistory.IsPending = 0 AND LotHistory.IsCancelled = 0

Comment: That is the sql I have written and now trying to do in c#

Comment: That SQL doesn't generate a sum.

Comment: that is the inner select statement I have and outer select statement that does the sum as the SQL query is too long for me to put here

Comment: You can't just keep changing your question. This answer solves the problem you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the data type of C column. If it not numerical then you need to modify your code to check the null value and cast the type and then sum it.

```
  public async Task<int> CountInPenLot(DateTimeOffset date)
    {
        int total = 0;
        var lotPensSum = await _context.LotPens
            .Where(x => x.DateColumn == date).toList(); //Filter on the date


        var lotHistorySum = await _context.LotHistories
            .Where(x => x.DateColumn == date).toList();

        foreach (var lotPens in lotPensSum)
        {
            if (lotPens.c != null)
            {
                int intC = 0;
                int.TryParse(lotPens.c, out intC);
                total += intC;
            }
        }

        foreach (var lotHistor in lotHistorySum )
        {
            if (lotHistor.c != null)
            {
                int intC = 0;
                int.TryParse(lotHistor.c, out intC);
                total += intC;
            }
        }

    return total;
    }
```