# Like operator in Linq(For integer)

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework-4, sql-like

In Linq we use the like operator for strings

```
var query = from c in ctx.Customers
            where c.City.StartsWith("L") && c.City.Contains("n")
            select c
```

Is it Possible to apply like operator in linq for integers.

please help me.

Comment: How would Like work with an integer?  What are you really trying to accomplish?  Can you give an example of how you wish to use Like with an integer?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: Actually I'm trying to implement a real time search for the customerID field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You'd have to cast to string first (see the answer here also: [Problem with converting int to string in Linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities)).

In SQL it would be something like

```
DECLARE @StartsWith NVARCHAR
SET @StartsWith = '1'

SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE (CAST CustomerId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE @StartsWith + '%'
```

I guess this should work in LINQ:

```
var query = from c in ctx.Customers
            where SqlFunctions.StringConvert((Decimal)c.CustomerId).Startswith("1")
            select c;
```

note that this will be a slow query if you have a large table, as it will need to do a table scan (any index on the int column would not be used).

Answer (score 0):

.Contains("/Integer/"))
You can also use .StartsWith() or .EndsWith().

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your integer field to a string, and then use `SqlMethods.Like`:

```
var query = from c in ctx.Customers
            where SqlMethods.Like(c.IntegerPhoneNumber.ToString(), "555*")
            select c
```

Comment: this didn't work for me, got an exception saying "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Like...." will try using eSQL instead.