# Linq query to fetch DB records corresponding to List of int[2]

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am trying to count the `VALUE`s corresponding to a `List<int[]>` using **Linq to Entity Framework**.

1. I have a `List<int[]>`  where each `int[]` in the `List` is of length 2.
2. I have a DB table `VALUES` which contains 3 columns, called `ID`, `PARENT` and `VALUE`, where each `int[]` in the `List` (see 1) ***may*** correspond to a record in the table, the 0 index being `ID` and the 1 index being `PARENT`. ***But** some arrays likely do not correspond to any existing records in the table.

Each combination of `ID` and `PARENT` correspond to multiple DB records, with different `VALUE`s.

Several points that are important to note:

1. One of the problems is that I can't rely on `ID` alone - each value is defined/located according to both the `ID` and `PARENT`.
2. None of the int arrays repeat, though the value in each index may appear in several arrays, e.g.

   ```
   List<int[]> myList = new List<int[]>();
   myList.add(new int[]{2, 1});
   myList.add(new int[]{3, 1}); //Notice - same "PARENT"
   myList.add(new int[]{4, 1}); //Notice - same "PARENT"
   myList.add(new int[]{3, 1}); //!!!! Cannot exist - already in the List
   ```

I can't seem to figure out how to request all of the `VALUE`s from the `VALUES` table that correspond to the `ID`, `PARENT` pairs in the `List<int[]>`.

I've tried several variations but keep arriving at the pitfall of attempting to compare an array in a linq statement... I can't seem to crack it without loading substantially more information that I actually need.

Probably the closest I've gotten is with the following line:

```
var myList = new List<int[]>();
// ... fill the list ...
var res = myContext.VALUES.Where(v => myList.Any(listItem => listItem[0] == v.ID && listItem[1] == v.PARENT));
```

Of course, **this can't work** because `The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.`

---

@chris huber

I tried it out but it was unsuccessful.
2 things:

1. Where you created "myValues" I have a DB table entity, not a List.
2. Due to point number 1, I am using LINQ to Entities, as opposed to LINQ to Object

My code then comes to something like this:

```
var q2 = from value in myContext.VALUES where myList.Select(x => new { ID = x.ElementAt(0), Parent = x.ElementAt(1) }).Contains(new { ID = value.ID, Parent = value.PARENT }) select value;
```

This returns the following error message when run:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ElementAt[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable` 1[System.Int32],Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

---

@Ovidiu

I attempted your solution as well but the same problem as above:

As I am using LINQ to Entities, there are simply certain things that cannot be performed, in this case - the ToString() method is "not recognized". Removing the ToString() method and attempting to simply have a   `Int32 + "|" + In32` gives me a whole other error about LINQ to Entities not being able to cast an Int32 to Object.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this workaround: create a new `List<string>` from your `List<int[]>` and compare the values in your table with the new list.
I didn't test this with EF, but it might work

```
List<string> strList = myList.Select(x => x[0].ToString() + "|" + x[1].ToString()).ToList();
var res = myContext.VALUES.Where(x => strList.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.ID).Trim() + "|" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.PARENT).Trim()));
```

Comment: I updated the question with the result of my attempt to use your suggested work-around.

Comment: Found a replacement for ToString() [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities). Instead of `x.ID.ToString()` use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.ID).Trim()`

Comment: Does this work for you in LINQ to Entities? I get an error message:

`The specified method 'System.String StringConvert(SystemNullable' 1[System.Double]' on the type 'Sysmte.DataObjects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following LINQ expression:

```
            List<int[]> myList = new List<int[]>();
        myList.Add(new int[] { 2, 1 });
        myList.Add(new int[] { 3, 1 }); //Notice - same "PARENT"
        myList.Add(new int[] { 4, 1 }); //Notice - same "PARENT"
        myList.Add(new int[] { 3, 1 }); 

        List<int[]> myValues = new List<int[]>();
        myValues.Add(new int[] { 2, 1 , 1});
        myValues.Add(new int[] { 3, 1 , 2}); //Notice - same "PARENT"
        myValues.Add(new int[] { 4, 1 , 3}); //Notice - same "PARENT"
        myValues.Add(new int[] { 3, 1, 4 });
        myValues.Add(new int[] { 3, 2, 4 }); 

        var q2 = from value in myValues where myList.Select(x => new { ID = x.ElementAt(0), Parent = x.ElementAt(1) }).Contains(new { ID = value.ElementAt(0), Parent = value.ElementAt(1) }) select value;
        var list = q2.ToList();
```

Comment: I updated the question with the result of my attempt to use your suggested work-around.