# why the date conversion is not working in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to mvc i had problem with following code it is throwing an exception:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `'System.String ToString(System.DateTime)'` method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
     public ActionResult JobSearchList(PostJobModel model)
     {
         try
         {

         if (Session["USER_ID"] != null)
         {
             var subscriber_Id = RL_Constants.RES_ID;
             var company_Id = RL_Constants.COMP_ID;
             var resource_Typa = RL_Constants.RES_TYPE;
             var jobPostDetails = (from jobPost in reslandentity.JOB_POSTING
                                   where jobPost.COMP_ID == RL_Constants.COMP_ID
                                   select new PostJobModel 
                                   {  
                                       POST_DT=Convert.ToString(jobPost.POST_DT),
                                       POST_END_DT=Convert.ToString(jobPost.POST_END_DT),
                                       POSITIONS_CNTS=Convert.ToString(jobPost.POSITIONS_CNT),
                                       JOB_TYPE = jobPost.JOB_TYPE,
                                       SKILLS = jobPost.SKILLS,
                                       DURATION = jobPost.DURATION,
                                       CATEGORY=jobPost.CATEGORY,
                                       PREREQUISITES = jobPost.PREREQUISITES,
                                       LOCATION=jobPost.LOCATION,
                                       RATE=jobPost.RATE,
                                       PERKS = jobPost.PERKS,
                                       CONTACT_PERSON=jobPost.CONTACT_NAME,
                                       CONTACT_EMAIL=jobPost.CONTACT_INFO,
                                       CONTACT_PHONE=jobPost.CONTACT_INFO,
                                       POST_TITLE=jobPost.TITLE,  
                                       DESCRIPTION=jobPost.DESCR                                                                                                                                                                    
                                   }).ToList();
             model.GetJobPostDetails = jobPostDetails;



         }

         return View(model);
     }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

     }
```

Comment: Why is your `PostJobModel` using strings to represent date/time values in the first place? That sounds like the thing to fix (along with your indentation, which makes you question hard to read).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities

Comment: this has nothing to do with MVC - this is an LINQ/LINQ2EF problem - and to be honest: the error-message says it all! The framework does not know how to translate your `Convert.ToString` into SQL ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty self explantory, `ToString` is not supported by the LINQ provider therefore you can't use it in a query.

Pull down the raw data and perform your conversions in memory.

```
var jobPostDetails = reslandentity.JOB_POSTING
   .Where(x => x.COMP_ID == RL_Constants.COMP_ID)
   .AsEnumerable() // materialize query, Select will be performed in memory
   .Select(x => new {
       POST_DT = x.POST_DT.ToString(),
       POST_END_DT = x.POST_END_DT.ToString(),
       POSITIONS_CNTS = x.POSITIONS_CNT.ToString(),
       ...
   })
   .ToList();
```

`AsEnumerable` will switch the context from `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` therefore allows for CLI-specific methods to be called as part of the query. The query will still only be materialized *after* `ToList` is called as `AsEnumerable` retains delayed execution.

Comment: This is only a good aproach if you really want to materialize this query into memory.

Comment: @JohannesWanzek the only part materialized into memory is the projection, the actual filtering is done server-side. The fact the OP needs to perform an unsupported method means they have to do this anyway. Not sure why this answer has been downvoted...

Comment: @James Maybe in this situation it works, but using LINQ it's not a good approach to do the materialization manually. Even with ToList.

Comment: @JohannesWanzek that statement is completely bogus, there *loads* of scenarios where materializing a query early is necessary, this is a primary example. In fact, `AsEnumerable` retains delayed execution and is the recommended solution for scenarios like this - you shouldn't downvote answers if you don't fully understand them.

Comment: @James Didn't know `AsEnumerable` retains delayed execution. So good answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) when trying to convert something **inside** a LINQ Query.

```
SqlFunctions.DateName("dd", jobPost.POST_DT) + 
SqlFunctions.DateName("mm", jobPost.POST_DT) + 
SqlFunctions.DateName("yyyy", jobPost.POST_DT) +
```

This functions can also be used inside where clauses etc.