# How to do I convert int to string in linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem converting int (long) to string. It throws me an exception when I am using  l.code == l.id.ToString().
id is type long and code is nvarchar.

The code i am using is

```
if (municipalityId != null)
    q = q.Where(l => l.MunicipalityId == municipalityId.Value && l.Code == l.Id.ToString());
```

Any help I would appreciate

Comment: What is the exception exactly?

Comment: What is the exception and its message that you get ?

Comment: what type is  `q` collection? Is it `IQueryable<T>` and exposed from EF ?

Comment: Sorry. The exception is: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(Int64)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: I a posting my method :                                                                                                      
            var q = _service.GetLocalities()
                .Select(LocalityViewModel.FromEntityExpression)
                .UnwrapLocalizedQuery();
                    
            if (municipalityId != null)
                q = q.Where(l => l.MunicipalityId == municipalityId.Value && l.Code == l.Id.ToString());
            q = q.OrderBy(l => l.Name);
            return Json(q.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: what version of entity framework are you using?

Comment: As the exception says, you just cannot use .ToString() in a LINQ to Entities expression.

Comment: Same problem is face here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities

Answer (score 0):

As [Matt Thrower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities) pointed out - this is problem in EF converting `ToString()` method into actual SQL type converting.

Try specifying SQL Function explicitly:

```
if (municipalityId != null)
q = q.Where(l => l.MunicipalityId == municipalityId.Value && l.Code == SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)l.Id).Trim())
```