# How to get last 2 characters from integer

Tags: c#

I need to get last two characters from an integer field coming through linq query.

Couldn't convert the integer field to String using Convert.ToString(),since LINQ doesn't support ToString().

any help?

```
int ret = db.tblProductionVolumes.Where(x => x.Month.ToLower().Equals(month.Substring(0, 3).ToLower()) &&
        month.Substring(month.Length - 2, 2).Equals(x.Year%100) &&
        x.BUId == namcID &&
        x.Type.ToLower().Trim().Equals(Constants.OS_VANNING)).Single().Volume; 
return (int?)ret
```

Comment: Something along `integer%100` ?

Answer (score 27):

You can use the modulus operator as such:

```
123 % 100 = 23
444 % 100 = 44
103 % 100 = 3 (needs to be padded)
```

Then you can pad the number, for numbers that would start with a zero.

```
(myNumber % 100).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')
```

Comment: I actually need to get the last two characters from a cloumn which holds year. Here is my code  
                        int ret = db.tblProductionVolumes.Where(x => x.Month.ToLower().Equals(month.Substring(0, 3).ToLower()) && month.Substring(month.Length - 2, 2).Equals(Equals(x.Year%100)) && x.BUId == namcID && x.Type.ToLower().Trim().Equals(Constants.OS_VANNING)).Single().Volume;
                        return (int?)ret;

Comment: when I use Module to get last two characters, I am getting exception "Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."

Comment: Maybe, the correct code could be:

`(number % 100).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'); `

Answer (score 6):

You can use integer modulo and div

```
Integer i = 1337
i % 10 will give 7
i / 10 will give 133
```

Answer (score 2):

For LINQ here is how to convert integer to string :

[Problem with converting int to string in Linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities)

Then you can use regular expression to take out last two characters from the string.