# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(Int32)'

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, compiler-errors

Hi I am using a linq query which is throwing the error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
        List<string> resultMap = (from item in mapResult
                                  select Convert.ToString(item.ResultDE)).ToList();
```

Error is throwing in this below statement

```
        List<Result_DE> resultList = (from result in db.Result_DE
                                      where result.IsActive == "1"
                                      && resultMap.Contains(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(result.ID)))
                                      select result).ToList();
```

please tell me the proper way of writing this query.

Comment: I have tried with the below statement. It executes but gives no output

            `List<Result_DE> resultList = (from result in db.Result_DE
                                          where result.IsActive == "1"
                                          && resultMap.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert(result.ID))
                                          select result).ToList();`

Comment: You're converting a string to an int and back to a string again?

Comment: what is the attribute of result.ID

Comment: What is type of result.ID?

Comment: I was converting string to an int and back to a string again because nothing was working, so i was trying out various combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use these conversion functions in a LINQ to Entities statement, they cannot be translated to SQL, you need to do the conversions in memory. But I don't think you need to do that at all.

If you were just using the `resultMap` to get your `resultList`, filtered by `Results` of which the `Id` is present in `mapResult`, do the following:

```
var resultList = db.Result_DE
    .Where(r => r.IsActive == "1" && mapResult.Any(mr => mr.ResultDE == r.ID));
    .ToList();
```

If `mapResult` is an in-memory collection, instead of an `IQueryable` that is attached to the `db` context, you need to do the following:

```
var resultIds = mapResult.Select(mr => mr.ResultDE).ToList();
var resultList = db.Result_DE
    .Where(r => r.IsActive == "1" && resultIds.Contains(r.ID));
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I edited your answer so that it now says Linq to Entities. You can update your comment if you think adding Linq To Sql to the mix is worth it. IMHO it was confusing and no one uses the term "Linq to DB"

Comment: @Pawel I agree, will leave it as is.

Comment: Thanks :) .. `mapResult.Any(mr => mr.ResultDE == r.ID)` worked

Answer (score 2):

Before you call any method (e.g. ToString()), you need to convert LINQ to Object using AsEnumerable().

Answer (score 0):

if your `item.ResultDE` and `result.ID` is variable type of Int32,
why don directly create a `List<Int32>` ?

```
List<Int32> resultMap = (from item in mapResult
                              select item.ResultDE).ToList<Int32>();

List<Result_DE> resultList = (from result in db.Result_DE
                                  where result.IsActive == "1"
                                  && resultMap.Contains(result.ID)
                                  select result).ToList<Result_DE>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SqlFunctions.StringConvert instead of Convert.ToString.

A similar question was asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3292773/4905310)