# filtering a list by an object having list of string properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Class

```
   public class AlldataPoints
  {
    public int phase{ get; set; }
    public string recr{ get; set; }
    public string study{ get; set; }
  }


public class filter
{
    public List<string> Phase;
    public List<string> recr;
    public List<string> study;

}
```

I have a list of above class say Alldatapoints 'lst' and an object of class filter 'obj'.

I want to filter only those rows of 'lst' that in which values of phases in      'obj' matches with 'lst' 'phases' and values of 'recr' in 'obj' matches 'recr' in 'lst' 'recr'. i want to use entity expression.

Comment: You have tagged with entity-framework. Is this "list of Alldatapoints" an actual `List<Alldatapoints>` or an entity set in your DbContext? This can affect the possible answers. If it is an actual list, then remove the entity-framework tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Contains` on the list of filter arguments:

```
filter obj;
IEnumerable<AlldataPoints> lst;   
var result = lst.Where(item => obj.Phase.Contains(item.phase) && obj.recr.Contains(item.recr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
public List<AlldataPoints> FilterPoinst(List<AlldataPoints> points, filter filter)
{
    return points.Where(x => filter.Phase.Contains(x.phase)
        && filter.recr.Contains(x.recr)
        && filter.study.Contains(x.study)).ToList();
}
```

If you need to match ony one property then just replace `&&` with `||` operator:

In your code just call this function:

```
var filter = new filter(); //init your filter
List<AlldataPoints> points = new List<AlldataPoints>(); // Here you should get your points
var filteredPoints = FilterPoinst(points, yourFilter); //you get your filtered points.
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Linq-to-Entities query  against your DbContext, you can still use [`Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) to check if each value is in each corresponding list.

Once awkward thing is that you need to convert `phase` to a string, as it is an `int` and the list is a `List<string>`, but you cannot just use `ToString()`, you have to use [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.stringconvert(v=vs.110).aspx) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities).

```
dbContext.AllDataPoints.Where(adp =>
    filter.Phase.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)adp.phase).Trim())
    && filter.recr.Contains(adp.recr)
    // && filter.study.Contains(adp.study)
)
```