# String combination does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Settings: asp.net mvc web app, azure sql db, EF code-first project

I am trying to combine 3 strings and a short into one string as given below:

```
CompanyAddress = company.ZipCode.ToString() + " " + company.City + ", " + company.Street + " " + company.StreetNr
```

ZipCode is a short, all others are strings. Using this code in a controller action returns no records (and no error message when run). When I omit the ZipCode part I get all records.

I also have tried ToString(company.ZipCode) and without .ToString(). Gives a wiggle-line (does not compile) and when run no error message and no records in return, respectively.
Please help.

Additional info:
The code line is part of an api controller (see below), ZipCode is nullable.
When ZipCode is part of the code line, then the controller delivers null, otherwise it delivers a proper string.

```
        var companies = UnitOfWork.GetAll<Company>();
        var query = company in companies
                    where company.Activ == true

                    select new ActiveCompaniesViewModel
                    {
                        CompanyAddress = company.ZipCode.ToString() + " " + company.City + ", " + company.Street + " " + company.StreetNr
                    };

        return query;
```

Comment: Is your ZipCode nullable ??

Comment: You're saying "zipCode is nullable" - but so is City, Street and probably StreetNr too! And if zipcode is anything but a string, then you're probably using the wrong datatype for it.

Comment: ToString(company.ZipCode) gives wiggle-line and does not compile

Comment: company.ZipCode.ToString() does run but does not return any records. The same with just company.ZipCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered before, 
[Problem with converting int to string in Linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities)

I think this will be your solution,

```
select new ActiveCompaniesViewModel
{
    CompanyAddress = (company.ZipCode == null ? "" : SqlFunctions.StringConvert((int)company.ZipCode) + " ") +
                     company.City + ", " +
                     company.Street + " " +
                     company.StreetNr
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked (does not make sense to me though!):

```
CompanyAddress = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal?)company.ZipCode) + " " + company.City + ", " +
                            company.Street + " " +
                            company.StreetNr,
```

Comment: ToString() on a short doesn't work as expected on LINQ to Entities, so we're using SqlFunction.StringConvert to do the conversion instead

Comment: I understand why we need SqlFunctions.StringConvert, but why 'decimal' is needed for a conversion from short to string seems strange to me.