# Entity framework: Retrieving data with column name and value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If I use:

```
private List<string> GetDataFrom()
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    using (var context = new mainEntities())
    {
        var matches = context.data.Where(s => s.Width == 500).ToList();
        result.AddRange(matches.Select(t => t.Key));
    }
    return result;
}
```

It is giving me perfect results, but I want to use a method where I can use column name and value, like this:

```
private List<string> GetDataFrom(string columnName, int valToMatch)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    using (var context = new mainEntities())
    {
        var propertyInfo = typeof(data).GetProperty(columnName).Name;
        var matches = context.data
                             .Where(p => p.propertyInfo == valToMatch);
        result.AddRange(matches.Select(t => t.Key));
    }
    return result;
}
```

This Method obviously doesn't work, so how can I do the same?
I am using SqlLite, so some answers given do not apply.
The whole problem is using propertyInfo the wrong way.

I tried various different approaches but no success.

This question is not a duplicate, because the suggested questions and their answers do not help much.
I like this question to be reopened.
I have found an answer myself I like to share.

Comment: You cannot make column names variable in this way, for the same reason you cannot write `SELECT * FROM @tablenameparam WHERE @columnnameparam = @valueparam` in normal sql

Comment: Im not following why you do it this way, what kind of model of entity are you using? 
How i would approach it is to look into the table the value i want (the name would be the column and the value well the value you are trying to get)

Answer (score 0):

ToString() method can not be translated into relevant SQL.

Try to use SqlFunctions.StringConvert(valToMatch) instead of valToMatch.ToString()

Answer (score -1):

```
.ToString()
```

Doesn't  works inside the Linq Query.

Inststed of .ToString() Function Use the following

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert()
```

SEE THE FOLLOWING ANSWER
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3292773/3736442