# Using `System.String Concat` in `LINQ to Entities` generates `CAST`s instead of `CONCAT`

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

As I can understand from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/clr-method-to-canonical-function-mapping), when one uses `string.Concat` from a querying technology, such as LINQ to Entities, this canonical function should be translated to the correct corresponding store function for the provider being used, meaning `Concat` for `MsSQL`'s `T-SQL`. But when I'm running the following test code:

```
var items = (from item in testDB.Items
            where list.Contains(string.Concat(item.Id,":"))
            select new
            {
               Hit = string.Concat(item.Id,":"),
               Item = item
            }).ToList();
```

the following SQL is being produced:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
     CAST( [Extent1].[Id] AS nvarchar(max)) + N':' AS [C1],
    FROM  [testDB].[Items] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (CAST([Extent1].[Id] AS nvarchar(max)) + N':' -- N.B.
    IN (N'1:', N'2:', N'3:')) AND (CAST([Extent1].[Id] AS nvarchar(max)) + N':' IS NOT NULL)
```

N.B.: `+`(Plus operator) with `CAST` instead of `Concat` is being used.
Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but what? The problem is that the `CAST` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` takes enormous amount of time, especially when several fields are being concatenated.

---

It looks like it cannot be done, since `Concat` uses `sql_variant` type, which is not defined by [`SQLProviderManifest`](https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/Resources/System/Data/SqlClient/System.Data.Resources.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.ProviderManifest.xml), overloading is not supported so only one function signature can be mapped(names in schema should be unique), so obviously they just made a short-circuit by concatenating using the plus operator with casts when needed, even when I mapped the `Concat` in code-first, the generated `SQL` was still using it so it became apparent. I think the only way is to utilize the `DbSet.SqlQuery`.

Comment: What is the database and C# type for `Id`?

Comment: Reverse your where clause by stripping “:” from the list items before Contains, it should be a lot more optimal.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius the semicolon used as a separator, this example is simplified for sake of brevity, the long version concatenates several fields and seeks matches within the list.

Comment: @NetMage the database is MsSQL 2016, the `Id` column is `int`

Comment: So, to do string concatenation with `int`, LINQ is going to throw in a cast to string. You could try forcing one manually with [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3292773/2557128).

Comment: @NetMage But 'Concat' doesn't require to cast explicitly, so why does `LINQ` do that? I'll try to use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` as workaround and will let you know.

Comment: That would be a question for EF developers, or possibly a bug report to them on github. While I don't think EF Core is ready for real applications, it is under more active development and you may get more traction there. Of course, EF Core may not handle this the same way.

Comment: @NetMage the question here is about EF6, and well yes, I totally agree with you regarding the readiness of EF Core for real world applications, that's why I'm still with EF6...

Comment: Yes, I know, but I doubt that EF6 will get this kind of bug fix.

Comment: @NetMage They're still working on updates, EF 6.3 on it's way, so anything is possible...

Comment: @NetMage `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` didn't help, it just added more overhead - `CASE WHEN (STR( CAST( [Extent1].[Id] AS decimal(19,0))) IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE STR( CAST( [Extent1].[Id] AS decimal(19,0))) END`, but the concatenation is still being performed using the plus operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to get things working we won't use `LINQ`, but `DbSet.SqlQuery`:

```
var contains = list.Aggregate(new System.Text.StringBuilder(),
                              (sb, s) => sb.Append($"N'{s}', "),
                              sb => (sb.Length > 0)
                                      ? sb.ToString(0, sb.Length - 2)
                                      : null);
if (contains == null)
{
  //ToDo: list is empty, we've got a problem
}
else
{
  var query = testDB.Items.SqlQuery($@"SELECT [E1].[Id],..
                                     FROM [testDB].[Items] AS [E1]
                                     WHERE CONCAT_WS(':', [E1].[Id],..) IN ({contains })");

}
```

It should be done with `SqlParameter`s of course, but this is the general idea for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

can use item.Id+":"
I used this usualy

Comment: It will produce the very same result, that's exactly where I've started.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove the concatenation from the SQL all together. It seems like you have a list of strings that contain numbers followed by a colon. Why not strip the colon from the numbers and do direct numeric comparisons?

```
var list2 = list.Select(i => int.Parse(i.Replace(':','')));
var items = (from item in testDB.Items
        where list2.Contains(item.Id,":"))
        .AsEnumerable()   // switch from DB query to memory query
        .Select(item => new
        {
           Hit = string.Concat(item.Id,":"),
           Item = item
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: This way it won't work, because list shall contain values to be compared against several columns and these values separated with a colon. Maybe the given example is oversimplified...